# Check a column with regexmatch for certain string plus at least one obligatory wildcard character in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here's an example

Mark S

Mark

Julia

Mark N

Markus

Lisa

Mark

Mark F

I want my formula to return the name as it is unless it's Mark with additional character(s) (yes, including "Markus"). In that case I want it to return (let's say) "different Mark".

I've tried different methods, the most elegant of which would be this:
=arrayformula(if(regexmatch(a1:a;"Mark*");"other Mark";a1:a))

If I could only get regexmatch to take the wildcard as an OBLIGATORY character. I've also tried "Mark?*" but even then, just "Mark" still returns as "true".

Answer (score 0):

*Try replacing `Mark*` with `Mark.+` and see if its givin' out the expected output*